# When to alexa-smapi and alexa-avs

Tags: automated-tests, mocha.js, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I need recommendations as when to use the above mentioned .Can i use
both of them is it possible .
Also in the botium.json's -

> Containermode

only one of these can be mentioned
how to understand what and when exactly I have to chose any one of these

Below is my botium.json file

> {
>       "botium": {
>         "Capabilities": {
>           "PROJECTNAME": "Alexa Conversation Sample",
>           "SCRIPTING_FORMAT": "xlsx",
>           "SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTROW": 2,
>           "SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTCOL": 1,
>           "CONTAINERMODE": "alexa-avs",
>       }
>       }   }

I want to know if I can use alexa-smapi or alexa-avs
for eg inwatson we use something like below in botium.json

> "CONTAINERMODE": "watson",
>         "WATSON_USER": "0274cb6f-3680-4cf7-bd6b-71c7f447542d",
>         "WATSON_PASSWORD": "ZWDE5xo02sby",
>         "WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID": "97513bc0-c581-4bec-ac9f-ea6a8ec308a9"

In the same sense how and what should i do to run alexa skill

Answer (score 0):

The [Botium Connector for Amazon Alexa Skills API](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-smapi) is for testing the Skill on a very low API level. You can test the intent resolution (with the Skill Simulation API), and the backend response (with the Skill Invocation API). **The recommendation is to start testing on API level with this connector.**

The [Botium Connector for Amazon Alexa with AVS](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-alexa-avs) simulates a virtual Alexa-enabled device connected to the Alexa services to test on End-2-End level - it uses Speech-to-text and Text-to-speech technologies to connect to your Alexa skill like a real user would do, and navigates through the conversation with voice commands.